# Understanding the notion of percentiles

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, order-statistics, percentile

I want to preface this by saying I am a beginner in probability.

I recently began reading the book "*Algorithms to Live By*", and so have been thinking about the optimal stopping problems for a while, specifically the Secretary Problem, and how this problem would change if information was provided regarding the distribution of the data points. I hence tried to understand what percentiles really tell you about relative standing.

**Here is my operational definition:**

Given a data set of size n, the percentile of a data point $X$ is value $ \pi(X) = \frac{|\{Y | S(Y)\leq S(X)\}|}{n}$ where $S:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ gives the score of a data point.

So, for example, if $n=100$ and $X$ is in the $95'th$ percentile, $.95 = \pi(X) = \frac{95}{100}$ as expected.

**Now here's a question:**

Suppose I have a data set of size $n$ and I pick a data point $X$ at random. Define $P_{y}(X)$ to be the probability that for this $X$ we have that $\pi({X}) > y$ for a given $y$. What, then, is a closed form for $P_{y}(X)$ in terms of $n$ and $y$?

Put more informally, given a random data point, what is the chance of it being in the $p'th$ or higher percentile for a given $p$.

**My informal attempt:**

For any given $y$, we have that $P(\pi(X) > y)$ is the same as $P( \frac{|\{Y | S(Y)\leq S(X)\}|}{n} > y)$. Obviously, we need that $y\leq1$.

Going back to the earlier example, with $n=100$, intuition tells us that $P(\text{ $X$ is in the $95'th$ percentile})$ should equal $.5$ percent. Since $95$ percent of data points $Y$ are s.t. $S(Y) < S(X)$.

We furthermore intuit that $P(\pi(X)>y)$ should increase if $y$ is small, but decrease if $y$ is large -- since more data fall above the $20'th$ percentile than the $90'th$. So we guess a solution: $P(\pi(X)>y) \approx 1 - \pi(X)$. This intuitively makes sense since $\pi(X)$ of the data has score less than $X$, and so for a given score $y$, we have that $1-\pi(X)$ of the data has score more than it.

**Problem**

How to formalize these notions? So far I have carried on informally and intuitively. How are these notions standardly defined in probability theory, and how my definitions and intuitions compare?

Comment: Stats.SE may better suit this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: Edited based on clarifications in the comments.

---

Let's say we have our dataset $D:=[X_1, X_2,...,X_n]\;,\; X_i \sim F_X$

We can translate this to the "scored" dataset $Q:=S(D) = [S(X_1), S(X_2),...,S(X_n)] := [S_1,S_2,...,S_n] $

We will also use "order statistic" notation to express the ranking of these scores in ascending order: $S_{(i)}$ means the $i-$th largest score in $Q$. We will also define $S_{(0)}= -\infty$ to simplify notation.

We can now define our *sample* percentile function (also called the *empirical cumulative distribution function*):

$$\pi_n(X) := \frac{|\{y:S(y) \leq S(X),\;y \in D\}|}{n}=\frac{|\{s:s \leq S(X),\;s \in Q\}|}{n}$$

Now, we will define $P_y(X;n)$ similarly to how you have (but explicitly mention $n$):

$$P_y(X;n) := P(\pi_n(X)>y),\;\;X\sim F_X,\;y \in [0,1]$$

The $n$ points in $Q$ define the locations where the value of $\pi_n$ changes:

$$\text{ Let }s\in\mathbb{R},\;\; i \in \{0,...,n-1\}:\;\;S_{(i)}\leq s < S_{(i+1)} \implies \pi_n(s) = \frac{i}{n}$$

So our $\pi_n$ function has "jumps" at each data point.

This means that

$$P_y(X;n) = P(S(X)\geq S_{(i)}) \text{ where $i$ is the smallest integer such that } \frac{i}{n} > y$$

In general, for a given sample, the sample percentile function $\pi_n(x)$ will not match the "true" percentile function $\pi(x):= P(S(X)\leq x)=F_X(x)$. The study of the behavior of order statistics is a [major field of study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) in statistics and the results are not simple.

However, the limiting behavior is much nicer -- specifically by invoking the [Glivenko-Cantelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem) we know that as the sample size gets larger, $\pi_n \to \pi$ as follows:

$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left|\pi_n(x)-\pi(x)\right| \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$$

In other words, the sample percentile function approaches the true percentile function *uniformly*.

So, your intuition was correct that $P_y(X;n)\approx 1-\pi_n(y)$. $P_y(X;n)$ is maximized at $y=0$ since $S(X)$ will have to be equal to or less than the smallest observed score in the dataset.

Comment: If I recall correctly, claiming that in general $F_X(X)\sim U$ is false

Comment: @Snoop — yeah, if it’s discrete or mixed it won’t be continuous— I should’ve been more careful with that. But regardless, the percentile and quantile relationship holds for the main OP question — there is a 1-p probability of X exceeding percentile p

Comment: @DavidK gotcha. I tried to address the finite-$n$ case in my second paragraph but you are correct that empirical percentiles are discrete and hence not all $y$ can be achieved exactly.

Comment: You might carry the result of the second paragraph forward into the rest of the answer. You then get a closed form in terms of $n$ as well as $y$, as requested in the question, and formalize the approximation that the OP "guessed".

Comment: @DavidK good suggestion :) will update in  a bit

Comment: @ User5678  can you explain this lone of reasoning? "therefore the probability that its percentile is less than or equal to  is ⌊⌋\" I am confused how if probabiliy of picking a point is $frac{1}{n}$ it implies that the probability of picking it as a percentile less than or equal to p is the epxession you provided.

Comment: @Shagester maybe I misunderstood this line “ Suppose I have a data set of size n and I pick a data point X at random.” to mean you are selecting from the $n$ points in the sample? Did you mean something else, like you pick a new point $n+1$ and want to know how likely it is to fall within a given sample percentile?

Comment: @User5678 I meant to say given a random data point, what is the most common percentile it can fall into, and what is the probability it falls into any given p'th percentile we choose? Intuitively, I want to say the 50th percentile would the most likely, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Shagester that is the relevance of $n$ in this?

Comment: @Shagester I think I get what you are trying to understand. The probability that a random variable $X$ is greater than the $p-$th percentile is $1-p$, which is maximized at $p-0$ because you are guaranteed to fall into this bucket. If you are talking about individual percentiles (e.g, 50th vs 51st) then, by definition, it is just as likely to fall into the 50th as the 51st (1% each) since both are 1 percentage point wide.

Comment: @Shagester -- redid my answer now that I think I understand. I cover the finite-sampling behavior in the answer.